# Graph DB with native support for Time Data Type

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, graphaware

Currently Neo4j doesn't support time data type natively. We can work around with using [long data type](http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/) or using GraphAware [TimeTree](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html).

Any reason why Neo4j doesn't support this natively? And is there any Graph DB with native support for time data type?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your use case for data type?

Comment: @MicTech, its mostly to model time series data as in what happened when. I have linked them with `next` as edge/relationship but there is  need for being able to slice the data to a particular datetime range. Also there are many parallel time series data exists within the same graph model.

Comment: From my point of view GraphAware time tree is what you're looking for.

Comment: InfiniteGraph supports Date, Time, and DateTime data types and is a schema-based object/graph database.

Answer (score 1):

I think Neo4j team have more important things to do, because long data type is good enough.

Also far as I know better data types are on the roadmap.